# Magento Database Repair Tool error

Tags: database

I want to use the Magento Database Repair tool, but it does not work.
I get the following PHP error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php:83 Stack trace: #0 /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php(1727): Tools_Db_Repair_Mysql4->setConnection(Array, 'corrupted') #1 /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php(1810): Tools_Db_Repair_Action->run() #2 {main} thrown in /magento-db-repair-tool-1.2.php on line 83
```

I used localhost as host. Because it is running on the same server.
I guess it is a php7 error, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mysql_*` functions (including `mysql_connect()`) have been [removed from PHP 7.0.0+](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php):

> **Warning** This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Note that Magento 1 [does not officially support PHP7](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html) (yet).